# Mixing edit access levels within the same mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, access-levels

I have my own mediawiki (running on a LAMP stack on an Ubuntu machine).

Some pages constitute my own scratchpad / diary. I don't want other people to edit them.

Other pages I would like to allow and encourage community editing.

However I don't want to have to crank up another webserver Machine instance to run another MediaWiki.

Is it possible to get both within the same mediaWiki installation?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You could use [$wgNamespaceProtection](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgNamespaceProtection), or plain page protection. More generally, see [Manual:Preventing access](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access).